# create jcombobox form enum depending on language

Tags: java, enums, combobox, properties, internationalization

I want to  create a jcombobox from enum values, which have different Strings depending on the Locale.
Right now I have:

```
     JComboBox roleBox = new JComboBox();
    roleBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(UserEnum.values()));
```

When I use UserEnum.values() I just get the String values from the enum. So how do I get the String values from the properties file?
My Enum:

```
public enum UserEnum {
    PATIENT("patientE"),
    DOCTOR("doctorE"),
    ADMIN("adminE");

    private String userEnum;

    UserEnum(String userEnum) {
        this.userEnum = userEnum;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.userEnum;
    }

    public String getString(Locale locale) {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle =ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.Enums", locale);
        return resourceBundle.getString(userEnum);}

}
```

Unfortunately I can't use UserEnum.values().getString :/ 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to visit each value of the enum and use its `getString` method separately in order to retrieve the strings. You can't call a method on a whole array. But creating an array of objects based on calling a method on objects in another array is a very common task.

First, don't forget that you need to retrieve the locale somehow:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
```

The traditional way of doing this would be:

```
UserEnum[] enumValues = UserEnum.values();
String[] localizedStrings = new String[enumValues.length];
for ( int i = 0; i < enumValues.length; i++ ) {
    localizedStrings[i] = enumValues[i].getString(locale);
}
```

Now you can use the `localizedStrings` array for your model or anything else.

The Java 8 way of doing the same is:

```
String[] localizedStrings = Arrays.stream(UserEnum.values())
                                  .map(val->val.getString(locale))
                                  .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have a tip how I then get the chosen UserEnum? When I use getselectedItem() i will get a String. Should I then use a swich case to see wich Enum was choosen?

Comment: Ah, that's a different issue. If you want an object that can actually return the enum, you should either create a wrapper object or, if you are always using the default locale, define the `toString()` in your Enum to `getString(Locale.getDefault())` and use the Enums themselves.

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum UserEnum 
{
   PATIENT("patientE"),
   DOCTOR("doctorE"),
   ADMIN("adminE");

   private final String userEnum;

   private UserEnum (String userEnum) 
   {
       this.userEnum= userEnum;
   }

   public String getuserEnum() 
  {
       return userEnum;
  }

   public String getString(Locale locale) 
  {
      ResourceBundle resourceBundle =ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.Enums", locale);
      return resourceBundle.getString(UserEnum.PATIENT.getKey());
  }
}
```